# Condition coverage missing in Saga Test case

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, redux, redux-saga

I have below line of code in `Saga.js` file. Not posting entire saga function but just the part of it where coverage is missing in my test. I have commented below which line coverage is missing in my test case.

```
const formData = yield call(constructApiData, modifyData) 
//constructApiData is function to modify the payload only. payload is `modifyData`

const response = yield call(postData, url, formData
// modified url formData is passed as payload for the post API call 

if(response.data.attributes.status === 'SUCCESS') { 
//COVERAGE MISSING FOR ABOVE LINE
yield put(saveRecommendations(response.data.attributes.recommendedPriorities));
yield call(onFormSubmitSuccess)
}
```

Here is the `Saga.test.js` file

```
expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(call(constructApiData, modifyData));
expect(gen.next(formData).value).toEqual(call(postData,'https://test.com', formData));

expect(gen.next(response).value).toEqual(put(saveRecommendations('priorities')))
expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(call(action.onFormSubmitSuccess));
```

How can i ensure i cover test coverage for this line in the saga.js file ->
if(response.data.attributes.status === 'SUCCESS') {

Answer (score 0):

Following the official doc: [Branching Saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing#branching-saga).

> Sometimes your saga will have different outcomes. To test the different branches without repeating all the steps that lead to it you can use the utility function `cloneableGenerator`

E.g. (Test strategy: test generator step by step.)

`saga.ts`:

```
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

export function constructApiData(params) {
  return { name: 'teresa teng' };
}
export function postData(url, formData) {
  return fetch(url, { body: formData });
}
export function saveRecommendations(payload) {
  return { type: 'SAVE_RECOMMENDATIONS_SUCCESS', payload };
}

export function* saga(onFormSubmitSuccess) {
  const modifyData = {};
  const url = 'https://test.com';

  const formData = yield call(constructApiData, modifyData);

  const response = yield call(postData, url, formData);

  if (response.data.attributes.status === 'SUCCESS') {
    yield put(saveRecommendations(response.data.attributes.recommendedPriorities));
    yield call(onFormSubmitSuccess);
  }
}
```

`saga.test.ts`:

```
import { constructApiData, postData, saga, saveRecommendations } from './saga';
import { cloneableGenerator } from '@redux-saga/testing-utils';
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

describe('64419302', () => {
  function mockOnFormSubmitSuccess() {}
  const gen = cloneableGenerator(saga)(mockOnFormSubmitSuccess);

  it('should construct api data', () => {
    expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(call(constructApiData, {}));
  });

  it('should call api', () => {
    expect(gen.next(constructApiData({})).value).toEqual(call(postData, 'https://test.com', { name: 'teresa teng' }));
  });

  describe('success', () => {
    let clone;
    beforeAll(() => {
      clone = gen.clone();
    });
    it('should save data', () => {
      expect(
        clone.next({ data: { attributes: { status: 'SUCCESS', recommendedPriorities: [1, 2, 3] } } }).value,
      ).toEqual(put(saveRecommendations([1, 2, 3])));
    });

    it('should call form submit success callback', () => {
      expect(clone.next().value).toEqual(call(mockOnFormSubmitSuccess));
    });
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64419302/saga.test.ts
  64419302
    ✓ should construct api data (4 ms)
    ✓ should call api
    success
      ✓ should save data (1 ms)
      ✓ should call form submit success callback

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   94.12 |       50 |      75 |   93.33 |                   
 saga.ts  |   94.12 |       50 |      75 |   93.33 | 7                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.923 s, estimated 3 s
```